# WPF Datagrid Showing Second DB Table As ComboBox Options

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have added a second table to my database which contains the different options i want to see in a combobox for each row of my datagrid in a new column. Each option has a key associated with it that matches up to a column in my main table, which is a value from 0 to 8. I have 2 problems, one of which i have resolved:

1. When the grid loads, i want the combobox column to show the [Description] that corresponds to each row's [Status] key. This is working.
2. I want the user to select the [Description] cell and have a dropdown open all of the possible [Description] options so that he can change the item's status.

For example, if a component goes on hold, the user needs to select that component in the grid and select "On Hold" in the dropdown of the status column.

The status correctly shows, but the dropdown doesn't populate with the 8 options from the CNCComponentStatus table. I am willing to bet i am not filling the dataset with the second table correctly in the SqlDataAdapter. That or i am not correctly using SelectedItem/ItemSource/SelectedValuePath correctly.

Here is a screenshot of the grid [image: grid]
Here is my data structure [image: structure]

These are the Status options:
[image]

Here's the xaml for the datagrid (only the pertinent parts):

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=test_3DimensionalDB}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="StatusColumn" Header="Status" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="cboStatus" Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox x:Name="StatusCombo" IsEditable="True" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Status}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Description}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And here's the method that grabs the data:

```
 Private Sub SelectQuery(ByVal company As String, ByVal status As String, ByVal component As String)

    Dim com As String = "SELECT tmfCNCComponent_threed.[CNCComponentKey]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[CompanyID]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[JobNumber]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[LogNumber]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[Customer]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[DueDate]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[JobLeader]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[CADProgrammer]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[Salesperson]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[CNCProgrammer]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ComponentDescription]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ComponentFilePath]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[Material]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ComponentSizeX]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ComponentSizeY]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ComponentSizeZ]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[QuantityShown]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[QuantityMirror]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[UpdateTime]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[Status]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ProgStarted]
    ,tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed.[Description]
    FROM [test_3DimensionalDB].[dbo].[tmfCNCComponent_threed]
    INNER JOIN tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed
    ON tmfCNCComponent_threed.Status = tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed.CNCComponentStatusKey 
    WHERE [ComponentDescription] " & component & " 'trode%' AND [CompanyID]='" & company & "' AND [Status]" & status & "ORDER BY [UpdateTime] DESC"

    Dim Adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(com, con)
    con.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Adpt.Fill(ds, "dbo.tmfCNCComponent_threed")

    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables("dbo.tmfCNCComponent_threed").DefaultView

    con.Close()

    RowCount()
    searchBox.Clear()

End Sub
```

Thanks for your time, sorry for the extreme detail.

EDIT:
Here is how i would attempt to populate the combobox since i am not binding properly. Although i don't quite understand how to show only one column instead of the DefaultView. Also, "StatusCombo" is inaccessible due to it's protection level?

```
    Dim com2 As String = "SELECT * FROM tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed"
    Dim AdptStatus As New SqlDataAdapter(com2, con)
    AdptStatus.Fill(ds, "dbo.tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed")
    StatusCombo.ItemsSource = ds.Tables("dbo.tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed").DefaultView
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to populate the ComboBox?

Comment: I don't have any, i was hoping if i use databinding correctly in the xaml i won't need any code. I tried making another dataadapter and filling the dataset again but that didn't work

Comment: Please show me anything at all that you did to populate the combobox. Absolutely anything anywhere. I don't mind if it's something you don't think of as "code".

Comment: I added an edit to the bottom of the post showing how i was attempting to populate the combobox in the code, but from what i understand i should be databinding in the xaml

Comment: OK, so you have more than one `StatusCombo` because it's in a template that creates one instance of it for each row in the table. Therefore its name is limited in scope to the DataTemplate where it's created. That's not negotiable. But that's OK; wisely, you don't want to do this in code behind anyway -- you want to use databinding. Critical question: **Do you have a viewmodel?**

Comment: Since you've got one set of Status options, you want to query those from the DB once, make a collection of the results, and populate *every* instance of StatusCombo in every row with the same collection of items. Not sure I understand *"show only one column instead of the DefaultView"*; are there columns in those results named "Status" and "Description"?

Comment: i do not have a viewmodel. The table which has the Description column that i am after also has a key column, this isn't important since i am not able to populate the combobox the way i have above

Comment: Please answer the questions I ask. I need to know what you are trying to populate the combobox with. OK?

Comment: I apologize if i am not answering your questions. If you look at the image of my database tables, you see my main table has a [Status] column. This matches up to one of the values in the other table's [CNCComponentStatusKey] column. I want to see all of the values listed in the combo that are in the [Description] column of the second table. So if i select "On Hold" in the combobox, the [Status] value changes to 2. When i open the combobox, i should see 8 strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what that combobox should end up looking like, I think. The x:Name property isn't needed. I doubt that IsEditable is needed either.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox 
            IsEditable="True" 
            SelectedValuePath="Status" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding Status}"
            />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

`SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` are strings. They're the names of columns in the data rows that populate the `ComboBox` (if you populate it with regular C# class instances, they would instead be the names of properties of the item class). You were trying to bind those properties to properties of a viewmodel you don't have, but even if you did have one, it wouldn't have those properties. But the concept of what a binding is and what it does can be weirdly slippery at first.

I almost told you to [read the documentation on SelectedValuePath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but the documentation has been revised and is now essentially meaningless. [DisplayMemberPath is better](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Second: You should have a viewmodel. The lack of a viewmodel makes everything more difficult. But you don't have a viewmodel.

What you need to do is get what you want from the database, and put it in some kind of collection somewhere that the combobox can be bound to.

Lacking a viewmodel to act as a natural home for that collection, we'll do that by creating a CollectionViewSource in your window's Resources.

```
<Window
    x:Class="blah blah"
    ...stuff...
    >
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Key="StatusItems"
            />
    </Window.Resources>
```

And we'll use that to populate the combobox like so:

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="StatusCombo" 
    SelectedValuePath="Status" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusItems}}"
    />
```

But our CollectionViewSource is empty. So we'll have to populate it somehow. We'll do that whenever you do the database query stuff.

```
Dim statusCVS As CollectionViewSource = FindResource("StatusItems")

Dim com2 As String = "SELECT * FROM tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed"
Dim AdptStatus As New SqlDataAdapter(com2, con)
AdptStatus.Fill(ds, "dbo.tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed")

Dim statusRows = ds.Tables("dbo.tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed").Rows
Dim statuses As New List(Of Object)

For Each row As DataRow In statusRows
    statuses.Add(New With {
            .Status = CInt(row("CNCComponentStatusKey")),
            .Description = CStr(row("Description"))
        })
Next

statusCVS.Source = statuses
```

This would be nicer than the loop, if it works:

```
Dim statuses = From row In ds.Tables("dbo.tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed")
               .Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)
               Select New With {
                    .Status = CInt(row("CNCComponentStatusKey")),
                    .Description = CStr(row("Description"))
                }

statusCVS.Source = statuses
```

OK, now we have this part:

```
    SelectedValue="{Binding Status}"
```

I'm guessing that `test_3DimensionalDB` (is your DataGrid actually populating?) must have some column that's a foreign key to the Status id value in the combo, and I'm guessing that it might be called `Status`.

So what we want to happen is: Say you have two items:

```
item 0:
    Status = 1
    Description = Dog
item 1:
    Status = 2
    Description = Cat
```

`DisplayMemberPath="Description"` means that item 0 will be displayed as "Dog", the value of its Description property. Item 1 will be displayed as "Cat" for the same reason.

`SelectedValuePath="Status"` means that when the binding sets SelectedValue to `2`, the combobox will look through its items collection to find the item that has a `Status` property equal to `2`, and select that item. If we set `SelectedValuePath="Fred"`, it would look for an item that had a property named `Fred` equal to `2`.

Likewise, if the user changes the selection himself, it goes the other way: Let's say the user selects item 0, so the ComboBox consults its own `SelectedValuePath`, sees "Status", and gets the `Status` property value (if any) of the selected item. For item 0, that's `1`. Then the combobox would assign that value of `1` to its own `SelectedValue` property.

The Binding on `SelectedValue` will then receive a notification that `SelectedValue` has changed, and it will get the new value and update the database row column it's bound to (also named "Status", in this case).

The `Binding` is an object that sticks around and does stuff. It's not a fancy word for "assignment".

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Status}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have adjusted everything to match your instructions above and i am getting an exception on startup stating "System.InvalidOperationException: The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets". The datagrid populated before i made these changes, it just didn't populate the combobox with Description options.

Comment: OK, you should then populate that combo with a collection of a trivial class [or an anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types), that has `Status` and `Description` properties.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do that but doing anything in visual basic is torture for me.

Comment: I think an easier approach would be to get rid of the second table, have [Status] as a string. And hard code the options for the combobox. Then when the user selects a value, update the row's status to the string value of the combobox selection.

Comment: The value in the row's Status column makes sense to the user, you could do that. I just updated my answer with some code that will probably populate the combo without blowing up -- can't test it because I don't have all your DB stuff, but it's at least very close.

Comment: hmm, i am still getting the same exception regarding multiple result sets. I also had to change your code where you have this : " .Status = CInt(row("Status"))," to  .Status = CInt(row("CNCComponentStatusKey"))," since [Status] is in the other table

Comment: Ahhh, OK, I think you may just need to dispose of the SqlConnection and recreate it in between queries for the main result set, and the statuses. I should have googled that exception.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much Ed, not only for the answer but for explaining the solution completely! The only thing i have to figure out now is why the data isn't updating when i change the combobox value

Comment: So does the databinding handle updating the database when changing combobox selection? Or do i need to create a CellEditEnding event to do that? Seems to not change the status after i make a selection

Comment: I don't know what "seems to not change the status" means. Are you saying the visible selection in the combobox doesn't change? Or that it's not updating the DataTable? Try `SelectedValue="{Binding Status, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"` and then watch the VS debug Output pane to see if there are any errors.

Comment: I'm not the best guy to ask here because I never use DataTable for anything. I use collections of POCO classes intialized from DB results. So binding to a DataRow, I have no experience. That might be a separate question.

Comment: To answer the last question, i can change my selection in the combobox, but the database is not updating the value to reflect the new selection.

Comment: What did you see from the trace on  the binding?

Comment: I can't debug out of VS, i have to build the app to my local inetpub folder since it runs in a browser, i get errors otherwise. So i don't think i can view the trace unless there is a way to write it to a log file

Comment: You can view the debug stream in [the indispensible DebugView utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview).