# WPF DataGrid ComboBoxColumn Not Updating Bound Data

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a dropdown column in my datagrid, the options for the combobox are stored in the **tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed** table. My main table has a column called [Status] which corresponds to the key column in that table.

The correct status [Description] is displayed in the combobox for each row in my datagrid, but when the user changes the selection, the database isn't updating, even though everything looks as though it is working properly. I have the "UpdateSourceTrigger" set to PropertyChanged as seen in many similar posts but still no dice. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="StatusItems"/>

                               <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="StatusColumn" Header="Status" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="cboStatus" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="StatusCombo" SelectedValuePath="CNCComponentStatusKey" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValue="{Binding Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusItems}}" IsEditable="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The code behind:

```
Dim com As String = "SELECT tmfCNCComponent_threed.[CNCComponentKey]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[CompanyID]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[JobNumber]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[LogNumber]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[Customer]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[DueDate]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[JobLeader]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[CADProgrammer]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[Salesperson]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[CNCProgrammer]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ComponentDescription]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ComponentFilePath]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[Material]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ComponentSizeX]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ComponentSizeY]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ComponentSizeZ]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[QuantityShown]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[QuantityMirror]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[UpdateTime]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[Status]
    ,tmfCNCComponent_threed.[ProgStarted]
    ,tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed.[Description]
    FROM [test_3DimensionalDB].[dbo].[tmfCNCComponent_threed]
    INNER JOIN tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed
    ON tmfCNCComponent_threed.Status = tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed.CNCComponentStatusKey 
    WHERE [ComponentDescription] " & component & " 'trode%' AND [CompanyID]='" & company & "' AND [Status]" & status & "ORDER BY [UpdateTime] DESC"

    Dim Adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(com, con)
    con.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Adpt.Fill(ds, "dbo.tmfCNCComponent_threed")
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables("dbo.tmfCNCComponent_threed").DefaultView

    con.Close()

    con.Open()
    Dim statusCVS As CollectionViewSource = FindResource("StatusItems")

    Dim com2 As String = "SELECT * FROM tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed"
    Dim AdptStatus As New SqlDataAdapter(com2, con)
    AdptStatus.Fill(ds, "dbo.tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed")

    Dim statusRows = ds.Tables("dbo.tmfCNCComponentStatus_threed").Rows
    Dim statuses As New List(Of Object)

    For Each row As DataRow In statusRows
        statuses.Add(New With {
        .Status = CInt(row("CNCComponentStatusKey")),
        .Description = CStr(row("Description"))
    })
    Next

    statusCVS.Source = statuses
    con.Close()


    RowCount()
    searchBox.Clear()
```

Thanks for your time.

The Database:

[image]

Contents of the Status table:
[image]

The Datagrid:
[image]

Here is the first part of this question that was addressed yesterday to get me to this point:
[Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354584/wpf-datagrid-showing-second-db-table-as-combobox-options)

Comment: `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is difficult to use. Stick with the template column. Did you try PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High and DebugView?

Comment: I couldn't get the debugger you linked in the other post working correctly on my windows 10 machine. it wouldn't show any debug info at all :(

Comment: Did you try Debug | Attach to Process?

Comment: Incidentally, you're making a big secret of exactly what's in `StatusItems`. Nobody can help you unless you say what's in there. Is it a collection? What's in the collection? Objects or DataRows? What are the names and types of the properties or columns?

Comment: I don't understand what i'm hiding? In the xaml above you can see that i declare my collectionviewsource. In the code, specifically the bottom part that you helped me create yesterday, you can see where i am filling the view source with data

Comment: Put the information for today's question in today's question. How is anybody but me going to know to go look there? Why should I believe you haven't changed anything, anyway? Come on, be serious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on information in comments in a different question, you probably need to change `SelectedValuePath="Status"` to `SelectedValuePath="CNCComponentStatusKey"`. The names of the columns or properties of the items in the combobox are critical to answering this question, and you haven't provided them.

The grid will update the DataRowView column value when the cell leaves edit mode.

`Mode=TwoWay` on that binding is unnecessary. That's the default mode for bindings on `ComboBox.SelectedValue`.

You can remove all those decorations from the binding on `TextBlock.Text`: It can't update the source at all, when you think about it, so there's no need to clutter up your XAML with elaborate instructions about how and when it should do something it can't do anyway.

---

### Complete working example

This is the code with which I tested the above answer. It updates the rows in the main table. It doesn't save the table to a database. That's a separate thing.

I don't know if your columns aren't called what you think they are, or what.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadData();
    }

    #region Lists
    private static List<String> _status = new List<String>
    {
        "Ready",
        "Not Ready",
        "Weary",
        "Disordered",
    };

    private static List<String> _words = new List<String>
    {
        "Ewwrigowasaus",
        "Skubreuph",
        "Creecroicr",
        "Eunthaudrawtr",
        "Ootwoww",
        "Meuleetroithr",
        "Rewshr",
        "Scoysl",
        "Scewziexul",
        "Kawxayzeec",
    };
    #endregion Lists

    protected void LoadData()
    {
        DataTable dtMain = new DataTable();

        dtMain.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(int));
        dtMain.Columns.Add("Programmer", typeof(String));

        _words.ForEach(w =>
        {
            var row = dtMain.NewRow();
            row[0] = ((int)w[0] % 2) + 1;
            row[1] = w;
            dtMain.Rows.Add(row);
        });

        DataTable dtStatus = new DataTable();

        dtStatus.Columns.Add("CNCComponentStatusKey", typeof(int));
        dtStatus.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(String));

        _status.ForEach(s =>
        {
            var row = dtStatus.NewRow();
            row[0] = dtStatus.Rows.Count + 1;
            row[1] = s;
            dtStatus.Rows.Add(row);
        });

        DataGrid.ItemsSource = dtMain.DefaultView;

        var cvs = (FindResource("StatusItems") as CollectionViewSource);
        
        cvs.Source = dtStatus.DefaultView;
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="StatusItems" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Programmer}" Header="Programmer" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ComboBox
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusItems}}"
                                SelectedValue="{Binding Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                SelectedValuePath="CNCComponentStatusKey"
                                x:Name="Combo"
                                />
                            <!-- Selected value in combo -->
                            <Label Content="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=Combo}" />
                            <!-- Value of Status column in row -->
                            <Label Content="{Binding Status}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have made all these changes, and now when i change one of the combobox values, all of them in the datagrid are changing to match lol. And they still aren't changing the database

Comment: Don't put the combo in `CellTemplate`, I deleted that suggestion because I saw the same ridiculous behavior. In `CellEditingTemplate` it works fine, except that you have to leave edit mode to get it to update, which is a drag IMO.

Comment: Since [Status] is the column in the main table that serves as the FK to the other table containing the combobox options, i think i do want [Status] as the SelectedValuePath. I want the binding to look at the row's [Status] value and lookup to corresponding Description of that status

Comment: You're wrong. You misunderstand what SelectedValuePath means.It contains the name of a property (or column) of the object (or row) in the ComboBox. Not the main grid. The ComboBox. The `SelectedValue` binding binds to the property of the main grid's row.

Comment: How do you expect it to look up the Description in the ComboBox? Based on what? Think about it.

Comment: O, based on the value of CNCComponentKey, not Status, i see your point. Thanks i'll keep at it

Comment: The database still isn't updating when i select a new value in the combobox. I have changed my SelectedValuePath to CNCComponentStatusKey as suggested.

Comment: Then there’s something you’re not telling me. Are you ever saving the data? Add a text column bound to Status to make sure it’s at least updating the column in the DataTable.

Comment: No, i am not in code at least. I was under the impression that UpdateSourceTrigger took care of updating the database after changing a value in the combobox

Comment: No. It does exactly what it says in the documentation. Don’t assume.

Comment: hmm, the status textboxcolumn doesn't change when i select a different combobox value. BUT if i changed SelectedValuePath back to [Status] it does.

Comment: Not my problem.

Comment: No it's not, i was just informing you that i added the column as you suggested and reporting the results of the test. Thanks for the help, i won't take up any more of your time.